# How to align text_field center in a form column with button in same row while the text_field width is lessened?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

**Issue:**  I have a single text_field form with a submit button within a tables column.  When I align the button to the right of the text_field, it pushes the entire form to the left and pushes all of the other columns as well.

I do believe the width: 85px (below) is effecting this but there needs to be a fix for this SOMEHOW

```
<td class="center">
  <div class="input-group">
    <%= form_for user, remote: true do |f| %>
       <%= f.text_field :field, class: "form-control center", style: "width:85px;"  %>
       <%= f.button data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: "btn btn-light" do %>
          <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</td>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h9qrspdn/1/

The input-field doesn't work in the jsfiddle for whatever reason.  But it puts the button in the same row and to the right of the text field.  But you see my issue

This is all bootstrap 4 btw

There are 4 columns and the form is in the last column on the right side.

If I don't have the `<div class="input-group">`, everything is centered (aside from the font awesome button but that's a different issue - and i tried it with a regular f.submit and the same issue persists) within the forms column how it should be but the button is under the text_field.  Once I had the `<div class="input-group">` the button aligns to the right of the text_field, but then all of the columns shift about 10% to the left, and also the text_field/button are aligned to the left within its' column.

If there is a way to keep somehow position the button to the right without needing to use input-group? I feel like that may help it stay in the centered position and just have the button tack onto the right side.

How can I shift both the text_field/button to the center, and not effect the table to push the other elements?

Comment: Could you provide HTML instead of pre-rendered template? and also the relevant CSS please

Comment: @JeremyThille Added - thanks

Comment: so it looks like the issue is form-control.

Comment: I just set `display:flex` on the form and the button is on the right and all looks good, I'm not sure where the problem is? https://jsfiddle.net/egk0tr9u/1/

Comment: Setting your inputs to `display: inline-block`, or floats or using `display: flex;` on the form container as suggested by @JeremyThille fixes the problem.

Comment: I could be doing something wrong but when i use the css applied the the rails form_for it doesn't fix it.  The only thing that fixes it is removing "form-control".  Something in bootstrap must be doing this and i may need to somehow either override form-control or just apply custom css to the field